# Least Cost Path Pluging - points ID

Tags: cost-path, least-cost

I am using the Least Cost Path Plugin (https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/leastcostpath/), which works perfectly. The "id" produced in the "output least cost path" layer takes a unique value ranging from 1 to 1632, as I have 1632 ending points. However, in the ending point layer that I use, there is only one field that I called "id" with an unique ID code for each of the ending point. Hence, I would like that the "output least cost path" layer returns these unique ID codes from my ending point layer instead of these random ID numbers.